# reactjs: images routes to /static/image path

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I have a component with following code

```
// Images
import bgImage from "assets/images/bg-sign-in-basic.jpeg";

import google from "./Actions";

function Basic() {
  return (
    <BasicLayout image={bgImage}>
      <Card>
....
```

I have used aws amplify to deploy this code

When i check the site it shows

```
https://tesyryey.com/static/media/bg-sign-in-
basic.f327db1d0e4b00ba3c81.jpeg
```

I have put the site on aws amplify.

and this image is not loading because there is not path /static/media

what to do

On my localhost:3000 this image loads

```
http://localhost:3000/static/media/bg-sign-in-basic.f327db1d0e4b00ba3c81.jpeg
```

The files structure:

[image]

Comment: is your JS file and assets folder in the same directory?